# How to add auto increment primary key based on an order of column?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I need to add an auto increment id to an already existing table. I did:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name)
```

However, the auto numbering wasnt based on any particular column order. I want mysql to smartly put auto numbers based on the order of certain column. Is it possible?

Most of the answers out there tell you how to add auto increment fields, not how to control those numbers in already existing table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a new field - `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INT FIRTS;`
2. Populate data in the new field.
3. Make this field as part of primary key and add AUTO_INCREMENT option -

   ALTER TABLE table_name
     CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

**EDIT:**

Try this plan:

1. Create another table, the same as `table_name`.
2. Populate new table with sorted data from `table_name` table:

   INSERT INTO temp_table_name SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name;
3. Empty `table_name` table:

   TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
4. Alter `table_name` table, add new auto increment field and make it primary (your code).
5. Copy data from temp. table to the `table_name`:

   INSERT INTO table_name SELECT NULL, t.* FROM temp_table_name t;

Comment: Thanks for your answer devart. In step 2, I dont want to populate the field manually. Rather have them auto filled based on the sort order of column_name

Comment: I have added one more solution.

Answer (score 17):

Note that MySQL table can only have one column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute.

Assuming the table **doesn't have a primary key**:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_id INT NOT NULL;
SET @x = 0;
UPDATE table_name SET new_id = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY whateveryouwant ASC;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY new_id (new_id);
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE new_id new_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Assuming the table **already has a NON-incremented primary key**:

Just ommit the `PRIMARY` keyword in the fourth command.

Comment: You can have an auto-Incrementing column that is not the PRIMARY KEY, as long as there is an index (key) on it. you can use this code to add index to column ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX new_id (new_id);

Comment: Works like a champ!  Up voted.  Unfortunately it takes about 2.5 times as long as just adding an auto_increment without specifying an order so we could not use it because it was not absolutely necessary and would have made our system down time too long.  Love the solution nonetheless!